# Raman process and stimulated Raman adiabatic process?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

what is the difference between Raman process and stimulated Raman adiabatic process?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.